# Does ExtJS support 3D charts?

Tags: extjs

I am using the ExtJS column chart for a project and would like to change the look to a 3D chart.  Is this supported by ExtJS, or are there plans to support 3D charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Ext3 charting uses a flash library that doesn't support 3D charts, in Ext4 they switched to Canvas charts but haven't built in support for 3D charts either.

You could take a look at [ux.Media.ChartPack](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?32434-ux.Media.ChartPack-2.1.2-%28Fusion-OFC2-amChart%29-released.) which integrates [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) among other charting libraries. They probably support 3D charts. FusionCharts does.

Check http://demos.theactivegroup.com/?demo=charts&script=fusion# for a demo with 3D Pie charts, other charts should integrate similarly.